# QML, failed by using components of another qml file

Tags: qt, menu, qml

I have a problem with the usage qml components from another qml file. I have 2 files, `main.qml` and `menu.qml` (`menu.qml` is in another folder called `menu`). In the `menu.qml` I have my menu, which I want to use in `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Menu {
    id: routingMenu
    width: maximumWidth
    height: 200
    y: 20
    cascade: true
    Rectangle {
        Label {
            x: (app_window.width / 8)
            text: "FROM:"
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.italic: true
            color: "black"
        }
        Label {
            y: routingMenu.height / 7
            text: "Country:"
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.italic: true
            color: "black"
        }
        Label {
            y: routingMenu.height / 2.5
            text: "City:"
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.italic: true
            color: "black"
        }
        Label {
            y: routingMenu.height / 1.6
            text: "Street:"
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.italic: true
            color: "black"
        }
        Label {
            y: routingMenu.height / 1.2
            text: "Postal Code:"
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.italic: true
            color: "black"
        }
    } //Rectangle

    Rectangle {
         x: app_window.width / 2
         Label {
             x: (app_window.width / 4)
             text: "TO:"
             font.pixelSize: 22
             font.italic: true
             color: "black"
         }
         Label {
             y: routingMenu.height / 7
             text: "Country:"
             font.pixelSize: 22
             font.italic: true
             color: "black"
         }
         Label {
             y: routingMenu.height / 2.5
             text: "City:"
             font.pixelSize: 22
             font.italic: true
             color: "black"
        }
        Label {
            y: routingMenu.height / 1.6
            text: "Street:"
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.italic: true
            color: "black"
        }
        Label {
            y: routingMenu.height / 1.2
            text: "Postal Code:"
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.italic: true
            color: "black"
        }
    } //Rectangle

    Button {
        id: sendDataToItem
        width: 100
        height: 40
        x: app_window.width / 2.7
        text: "Send"

        onClicked: {
            //fromAddress.country: "";
            //fromAddress.city: "";
            //fromAddress.street: "";
            //fromAddress.postalCode: "";

            //toAddress.country: "";
            //toAddress.city: "";
            //toAddress.street: "";
            //toAddress.postalCode: "";
        }
    } //sendDataToItem
} //Menu
```

I tried to use a Component, but it didn't helped me. That is code of my main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
import "menu"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: app_window
    visible: true
    width: maximumWidth
    height: maximumHeight
    title: qsTr("Navigation")


    PositionSource {
           active: true
           onPositionChanged: {
           //map_id.center = position.coordinate;
           }
    }

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin_
        name: "osm"
    }

    /*Loader {
            id: loadered
            focus: true
            source: "menu/menu.qml"
            active: true
        }*/


    Rectangle {
         id: mapRectangleID
         width: 800
         height: 800
         x:0
         y:20

         Map {
            id: map_
            anchors.fill: parent
            plugin: mapPlugin_
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(51.320729390711975,12.280097007751465)
            zoomLevel: 15

            MapQuickItem {
                       id: marker_id
                       coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75)
                       sourceItem: Image {
                               id: endPointImage
                               source: "assets/marker.png"
                               width: 100
                               height: 100
                       } //size and position of maker
                       anchorPoint.x: endPointImage.width / 2
                       anchorPoint.y: endPointImage.height
            } //marker

            RouteModel {
                    id: routeBetweenPoints
                    plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
                    query: RouteQuery {id: routeQuery }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                    routeQuery.addWaypoint(QtPositioning.coordinate(51.318784,12.2773504 ));
                    routeQuery.addWaypoint(QtPositioning.coordinate(51.3117764,12.280909000000065 ));
                       //routeQuery.addWaypoint(endPointGeaocodeModel)
                    update();
                    }
            } //start and end point

            MapItemView {
                model: routeBetweenPoints
                delegate: Component {
                    MapRoute {
                        route: routeData
                        line.color: "red"
                        line.width: 10
                    }
                } //Component
            }//linie, die beide punkte verbindet

            GeocodeModel{
                 id: endPointGeaocodeModel
                 plugin: Plugin { name: "osm" }
                 query: "Sandakerveien 116, Oslo"
                 onLocationsChanged: {
                     if (count> 0){
                        marker_id.coordinate = get(0).coordinate
                        map_id.center = get(0).coordinate
                     }
                 }
                     Component.onCompleted: update()
            } //suche den platz mit strasse und stadt








            //! [geocode0]
            Address {
                id: fromAddress
                city: ""
                country: ""
                street: ""
                postalCode: ""
            } //fromAddress
            //! [geocode0]

            Address {
                id: toAddress
                country: ""
                city: ""
                street: ""
                postalCode: ""
            } //toAddress



         } //Map
    } //mapRectangleID

    Button {
        id: btn_close
        width: 100
        height: 20
        text: "Close"

        onClicked: {
           Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: btn_routing
        width: 100
        height: 20
        x:100
        text: "Routing"

        onClicked: {
             routingMenu.open();
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: btn_oldWay
        width: 100
        height: 20
        x:200
        text: "Old way"

        onClicked: {
             oldWayMenu.open();
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: rest
        width: parent.width - x
        height: 20
        x:300
        text: ""

        onClicked: {
        }
    }
} //ApplicationWindow
```

I tried 2 ways to resolve the problem. One with the Loader, but I can't open my menu, and the another with example of QT which is in MapViewer Example. They import only the order and use the id of the component. But it doesn't work. I think, I do something wrong in my code, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or show me the right way to resolve my problem.

I think that the most important part of the code is:

```
Loader {
        id: loadered
        focus: true
        source: "menu/menu.qml"
        active: true
    }
```

And then, how I'm using it:

```
Button {
    id: btn_routing
    width: 100
    height: 20
    x:100
    text: "Routing"

    onClicked: {
         routingMenu.open();
    }
}
```

By the button I'm using the component name, because I imported menu. But if I want to use the loader, I would set the visible in loader as false and then set onClicked as true. But I tried this and it didn't work.

Thanks for help
DC

Comment: Yikes that's a lot of code. Might discourage any potential answerers. : (

Comment: I think, now it will be better. I wrote, which part of the code can be a proble. And thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is only valid within the .qml outside it has no meaning, for example let's say you're going to create 4 menus then if you would use the id routingMenu, which of the menus would you refer to? because that would cause confusion. So if you want to use the item loaded by [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) you must do it using the [item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) property.

```
Loader {
    id: loadered
    focus: true
    source: "menu/menu.qml"
    active: true
}
// ...

Button {
    id: btn_routing
    width: 100
    height: 20
    x:100
    text: "Routing"
    onClicked: loadered.item.open()
}
```

Comment: Ok, i thoght that i need to use the component property. But what is, when I have the button in the menu.qml and I want send the data to main.qml? Should i load the main.qml to menu.qml and then use the component as item?

Comment: @DragonCoder No, you are making the components too intertwine, you should think that the menu component is a black box that exposes its inputs and outputs, in the case that you indicate you must create a signal in the top of the menu so it will be visible from outside. , and that signal must be emited when you press the button

Comment: what is `txtFromAddressCountry`? Have you read the docs? In the documentation there is an example of what you should do: [Receiving Signals from Loaded Objects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#receiving-signals-from-loaded-objects)

Comment: txtFromAddressCountry is the inputfield. Oh okay,I rode the wrong document. thanks